# Why comma ' , ' and plus ' + ' log the console output in different pattern?

Tags: javascript

I am using the console.log statement for debugging , but came across a scenario where using ',' or '+' with console.log statement  is logging the output in different pattern.For example

```js
(function() {
  var x = [];
  x.push({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  }, {
    a: 4,
    b: 3,
  }, {
    a: 5,
    b: 6
  }, {
    a: 7,
    b: 8,
  })
  console.log('Logging with , ', x);
  console.log('Logging with + ' + x);
}())
```

When I am using ',' with console.log I am seeing output as

```
Logging with ,  [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

and each of this object is expandable.But with '+' I am seeing output as

```
Logging with + [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

For demonstration I have created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj5q7c50/).

Can you please help me understanding why we see this difference.

Comment: With a `+`, you get stringified version of an object. Whereas with `,`, the original object is logged.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`+`(*string concatenation operator*) with object will call the `toString` method on the object and a **string** will be returned.
So, `'' + object` is equivalent to `object.toString()`. And `toString` on object returns `"[object Object]"`.

With `,` the object is passed as separate argument to the [log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) method.

Answer (score 18):

To add possibly a little more clarity (or verbosity) with examples to [Tushar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) response:

With respect to concatenation (excluding `console.log()` stuff) use the + operator.
The reason why you use comma in `console.log()` is because of the parameters that function takes is a variable amount of arguments.

So, if you do    `console.log('a' + 'b')`, you get    `ab`

but, if you do `console.log('a' , 'b')`  you get `a b`

Now, if you do `console.log('a' + {a : 'a'})`  you get
`a[object Object]` which isn't very useful,

whereas if you do `console.log('a' , {a : 'a'})` you get `a {a: 'a'}`

So, the comma passes the object as a parameter, which uses the `toString()` of that object, which is preferable for `console.log()`.

Comment: Your last line is actually wrong. It should be _"So, the comma passes the object as a parameter which uses internal magic to display that object so beautifully."_