# Setting date in nodejs date object shows date as different value

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

When i'm setting up date object using the below statement the output showing different in nodejs. Can you please help me to understand why it is like this. And how i need to pass to print right value.

```
var date1= new Date(2017,01,01);
var date2= new Date(2017,01,31);
console.log("2017-01-01 is printed as ==>",date1);
console.log("2017-01-31 is printed as ==>",date2);
```

Output

> 2017-01-01 is printed as ==> 2017-01-31T18:30:00.000Z
>
> 2017-01-31 is printed as ==> 2017-03-02T18:30:00.000Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing your logs like this
`console.log("2017-01-01 is printed as ==>"+date1);
console.log("2017-01-31 is printed as ==>"+date2);` 
will give you your expected logs
It is because console log will take date as object of date while using comma and while using `+` it will apply `object.toString()` to date object.

Answer (score 0):

Month parameter  starts from 0 (January) to 11 (December)
so if you want to get 2017-01-01 you need to use:

```
var date1 = new Date(2017, 0, 1)
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

Comment: after doing your suggestion still it is print as same 

`var date1= new Date(2017,0,1);
var date2= new Date(2017,0,31);
console.log("2017-01-01 is printed as ==>",date1);
console.log("2017-01-31 is printed as ==>",date2);
`
Output
2017-01-01 is printed as ==> 2016-12-31T18:30:00.000Z
2017-01-31 is printed as ==> 2017-01-30T18:30:00.000Z

Comment: can you try printing your logs like this  
`console.log("2017-01-01 is printed as ==>"+date1);
console.log("2017-01-31 is printed as ==>"+date2);` ?

Comment: @TGW is there a difference? The logging with the comma appears to work the same.

Comment: @StevenTang using comma will pass this `date1` and `date2` as an object to the log method while using `+` will invoke object.toString on the date object and print the date. Hence such different behaviors. [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339688/why-comma-and-plus-log-the-console-output-in-different-pattern) on stack might give you more explanation.

Comment: @TGW Could you please update this in answer section so that I can make this question as answered .

Comment: After little search I also found little more thing... console.log if the object type is date,It invoke ISoDateString() method https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L525. Please check line no 525.  Thank you so much TGW.

Comment: @Vipin glad it helped