# Date issus in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I have a probleme with date manipulation NodeJs Exemple :

Sysdate is : Mer 28 mar 2018 10:38:49 CEST

```
   console.log('TimeZone :', process.env.TZ) // Europe/Paris

    let maDate = new Date(); // New 

    console.log('maDate--------: ', maDate) // 2018-03-28T08:34:16.926Z

    console.log('maDate with tZ', maDate.toLocaleDateString({
        timeZone: 'Europe/Paris'
    }))    //2018-03-28T10:34:16.926Z
```

When i send the request to database, they take the seconde one (Good Time) but when i print in console ( i have alltime the GMT Hours).

I have tried this but not work .. !

```
   env TZ='Europe/Paris' node ./bin/www.js
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) If you're having trouble with your code sending a request to the database, why wouldn't you show your code sending a request to the database?

Comment: What is the column type in your database that hold your date value, also show the statement that is executing your query for database insertion.

Comment: i want to print proprly the date ! in my console

Comment: new Date() gives time in UTC timezone and i want the local time !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting date in nodejs date object shows date as different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047000/setting-date-in-nodejs-date-object-shows-date-as-different-value)

Comment: The problem i think is REPL of nodejs