# Javascript Array shows value for individual property but not full array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tried searching with no luck.  Am new to JS, sure I'm missing something straightforward.  Trying to find out why, when I post to console, my array appears empty - even though there is at least one property-value pair.

```
  function getCash(denom,value){
    if (change>value&&cashRegister[denom]>=value){
       change-=value;
       cashRegister[denom]-=value;
       cashRegister[denom]=cashRegister[denom].toFixed(2);
       if (changeBack[denom]==undefined) changeBack[denom] =0;
       changeBack[denom]+=value;

// Below shows "changeBack[denom]=QUARTER 0.25" as expected 
       console.log("changeBack[denom]="+denom+" "+changeBack[denom]);

//Below shows "changeBack="  I expected to see the object, tried to stringify but still empty.
       console.log("changeBack="+changeBack);


    }
  }
```

Comment: put the debugger on if condition and check, I think that conditions are not getting satisfied.

Comment: Arrays in JS are (primarily) numeric arrays, not associative arrays. That's why your keys don't show in the logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in JS are (primarily) numeric arrays, not associative arrays. 
That's why your keys don't show in the logger.

But since JS is flexible as heck and Arrays in JS inherit from Object you can add arbitrary keys to them. Still doesn't make them associative Arrays.

So, use Objects `{}` as associative Arrays.

And don't concat strings and other values to log them. Use multiple arguments: `console.log("changeBack", changeBack);` so you can inspect every single value in the console.

Comment: Changed to object and everything is working now.  Thank you.'changeBack' declaration to changeBack={};

Answer (score 1):

`console.log("changeBack="+changeBack)` should be `console.log("changeBack=", changeBack);`

Additional context from [another answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339696/11998782)

> `+`(*string concatenation operator*) with object will call the
>   `toString` method on the object and a **string** will be returned. So,
>   `'' + object` is equivalent to `object.toString()`. And `toString` on
>   object returns `"[object Object]"`.
>
> With `,` the object is passed as separate argument to the [log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)
>   method.

Comment: Assuming you're running this in Chrome, add a `debugger;` (or a breakpoint)  above your first console.log(), and press F10 until you're on the line that is giving you errors, and hover over the object to make sure it's got the values you think it should have

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it as a separate log and you'll see your object.

```
console.log(changeBack);
```

Comment: When I do that all I get is an empty array "[]"