# JSON string won't print to console

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have this service:

```
getCert(p: string): Promise<string> {
  return ApiService.getData(this.apiUrl + p + this.certEndpoint).then(
    (response) => response.data
  );
}
```

This is an example of `data`:

```
{
    "state": "success",
    "message": "Message received."
}
```

If I return `response.data.state` or `response.data.message` I get the relevant value.

If I call it with this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const queryString = require('query-string');
    const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
    return this.docListingService.getPks(parsed.policy).then(async pks => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, packs });
        this.certService.getCert(parsed.policy).then( response => {
            console.log('RESPONSE: ' + response);
        });
        return pks;
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.loggingService.logError('Error returning Docs ' + error);
        this.setState({ errorOccured: true});
    });
}
```

`response` is a string but my `consle.log` prints `RESPONSE [object Object]`. I tried `console.log('RESPONSE: ' + response.state);` and `console.log('RESPONSE: ' + response.message);` but they error. As does:

```
console.log('RESPONSE: ' + JSON.parse(response));
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof response, response)` show? Also you say "_they error_", but what error do they throw exactly?

Comment: try using [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) console.log("Response: ${response}"). Use backticks ` instead of ". Or use `comma ,` instead of + [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339696/13405106)

Comment: response is an object, if you use the + operator on it it acts as a concatenator so that's what you get, just try console.log(response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` accepts as many arguments as you like. So you can just use it like this:

`console.log('response ', response)`

If you want to log multiple variables, you can do it like this:

`console.log(variable1, variable2, variable3, 'some string', variable4);`

Comment: Sure, but this most likely doesn't explain the underlaying problem, which is that `response` isn't what OP expects it to be. (Also if this truly _is_ the answer, [we already have a duplicate for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339688/why-comma-and-plus-log-the-console-output-in-different-pattern).)

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
JSON.stringify(response)
```

This will show the Object structure as string value.

Comment: Actually, above works but this is what I really wanted: `console.log('Response: ', response);`

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug in console.log of your code, you are trying to concat a string and json object. you can try this code

```
console.log('response ', JSON.parse(response));

//or

console.log('response ', JSON.parse(response).data.message);

//or

console.log('response ' + JSON.parse(response).data.message);
```